# Where to check property availability on window in React lifecycle?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to have an information about [Device Orientation API](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-orientation-event-20160818/) support in one of my React Components. That's why I would like to have something like this (see code below) somewhere in the component lifecycle:

```
this.state = {
  isDeviceMotionSupported: 'ondevicemotion' in window,
}
```

I'm not sure if I reason correctly, but here is what I think:

- `constructor`, `componentWillMount` won't be a good places as I'm using server side rendering.
- `componentDidMount` won't be a good place because setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.
- `componentWillReceiveProps`, `shouldComponentUpdate`, `componentWillUpdate`, `componentDidUpdate` won't be a good place as they will be called many times, so we having this check there if I only need to do it once

Where would be the best place to put such check and why?

Comment: As far as i know it wouldn't matter if it's server side rendered or not, so i think componentWillMount would be the perfect place.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure `window` is available and reliable in `componentWillMount` on server side? Could you explain a bit more why is it?

Comment: Do you want the component to always know the device orientation, or just know what the orientation was when the component was first rendered?

Comment: @garrettmaring The second one: I want to know what was the orientation when the component was first rendered.